# sstableloader does not exit after successful data loading

Tags: datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0

I'm trying to bulk-load my data into DSE but sstableloader doesn't exit after a successful run. According to the output, the progress for each node is already 100% and the progress total also shows 100%

- Environment: CentOS 6.x x86_64; DSE 4.0.1
- Topology: 1 Cassandra node, 5 Solr nodes (DC auto-assigned by DSE); RF 2
- System ulimit (hard, soft) in each DSE node: 65536
- sstableloader heap size (-Xmx): 10240M (10G)
- SSTables size: 158gb (from 80gb CSV, 241m rows)

I tried to take down all nodes - hoping that sstableloader would somehow exit when one or more nodes go down - but it didn't. I had to kill the process manually either by 'kill' command or CTRL+C in the command window (SIGINT).

Prior to experiencing this issue with sstableloader not exiting, I had 1 successful run where it exited. I can't reproduce that anymore because sstableloader refuses to exit in all of my subsequent attempts regardless of sstables size

Answer (score 0):

Secondary indexes need to be built as well. But that shouldn't take hours.

Comment: An that is for every sstableloader run? I have 850gb mysql data (approx. 5B rows) which I'm breaking down into smaller chunks of export and import. If the secondary index needs to be rebuilt after every bulk-load, then I'm in trouble, right?

Comment: Actually, I cancelled the secondary index builds (via node restart) because they've been running for the past 1.5 days and all subsequent runs of sstableloader never finished. Now, the nodes are doing normal compaction but I still can't have a successful bulk load run. The last bulk-load-related line in the system.log of the nodes is "Received streaming plan for Bulk Load"